# Pygame: managing collisions when creating 20 randomly placed objects

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a simple simulation using Pygame. For start I need to create 20 objects and randomly place those along edges of the game window, excluding the top edge. `SingleCell` class manages objects and defines randomised starting positions for sprites.

This class is then being called in the main simulation class to create 20 sprites and add them to a group:

```py
def _create_cell(self):
        """Create a single sprite and add it to group"""

        for cell in range(0,self.settings.cell_count):
            c = SingleCell(self)
            c_width, c_height = c.rect.size

            self.cells.add(c)
```

This all works fine, but quite a few sprites end up overlapping. In order to fix it after studying docs for `pygame.sprite` I decided to use `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()` in a loop to check whether any of the sprites in a group do collide with one another and move them either horizontally or vertically by width or height, respectively, +1 pixel:

```py
def _check_overlapping_cells(self):
        """Check cells group for collisions based on rect"""

        for cell in self.cells:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(cell, self.cells,
                                           collided=None) != 'None':
                #If the collision happens along the vertical boundary
                #move the sprite down by 1 height +1 pixel
                if cell.rect.x == 0 or cell.rect.x == (
                        self.settings.screen_width - cell.rect.width):
                    cell.rect.y += (cell.rect.height + 1)

                #If the collision along horizontal edge then update x-coord
                #by sprite width +1 pixel
                elif cell.rect.y == 0:
                    cell.rect.x += (cell.rect.width + 1)
```

This worked. Sort of. Some of sprites would still be overlapping others in their new locations. So instead of `if` I've decided to use `while` cycle to keep moving them around until there are no more collisions:

```py
def _check_overlapping_cells(self):
        """Check cells group for collisions based on rect"""

        for cell in self.cells:
            while pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(cell, self.cells,
                                           collided=None) != 'None':
```

Unfortunately, this causes the sim to enter a seemingly neverending cycle of moving sprites around.

I'm a bit confused as to how to do it properly. Any advice?

EDIT:
I have since tried another approach of trying to check collisions when a sprite is being created by modifying `_create_cell` method so now it looks like this:

```py
def _create_cell(self):
        """Create a single cell and add it to group"""

        for cell in range(0,self.settings.cell_count):
            c = SingleCell(self)
            c_width, c_height = c.rect.size

            if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(c, self.cells,
                                           collided=None) != 'None':
                #If the collision happens along the vertical boundary
                #move the sprite up by 1 height +1 pixel
                if c.rect.x == 0 or c.rect.x == (
                        self.settings.screen_width - c.rect.width):
                    c.rect.y += (-c.rect.height - 1)
                    self.cells.add(c)

                #If the collision along horizontal edge then update x-coord
                #by sprite width +1 pixel
                elif c.rect.y == (self.settings.screen_height - c.rect.height):
                    c.rect.x += (c.rect.width + 1)
                    self.cells.add(c)

            elif pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(c, self.cells,
                                           collided=None) == 'None':
                self.cells.add(c)
```

But this way results in fewer than 20 sprites being created and some are still overlapping for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
def _create_cell(self):
    """Create a single cell and add it to group"""

    for cell in range(0,self.settings.cell_count):
        c = SingleCell(self)

        while spritecollideany(c, self.cells):
            c = SingleCell(self)

        c_width, c_height = c.rect.size
        self.cells.add(c)
```

Basically, the `while` loop keeps generating new Cells until it finds one that doesn't collide with any in `self.cells`.  Of course, it that is not possible, then it will loop forever.  You could add a counter and abort if it tries too many times.

Comment: Thanks! This works. So much simpler than what I was trying to do.